# browser vertical scrollbar fail

Tags: html, css

My vertical scrollbar on the rightmost side of the browser window appears correctly and scrolls correctly if:

- I make the browser window tall enough to show my site's entire landing page
- then collapse the height of the browser window so only the top 1/2 of the page is visible
- in which case the vertical scrollbar automatically appears and it correctly allows scrolling downward to see the rest of the page

Here's the CSS style that makes the vertical scrollbar visible:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html style="min-width: 100%">
 body
 {
   white-space: nowrap;
   height: 105%; 
   overflow-y: scroll; /* scrollbar always visible, stops page content shifting left */
 }                     /* due to the sudden appearance of the scrollbar on the right */
```

However, if I do the following, the vertical scrollbar on the right edge of the browser fails to work if:

- before loading the landing page, I reduce the height of the browser window so only the top 1/2 of my web page is visible when I load it
- then hit the 'reload' button in the browser
- in which case, the page reloads but the vertical scrollbar somehow is not 'noticing' the lower 1/2 of the web page -- the vertical scrollbar doesn't display enough 'scrollable capacity', ie. 'scroll offset', to permit scrolling down far enough.

The outermost divs on the page have these styles:

```
 .DivForCenteringThePage
 {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;      
 }


<div id="wholePageDiv" class="DivForCenteringThePage"> 
  <div id="outerDiv" style="margin: 0; margin-top: 10px; min-width: 100%; 
                     display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="leftSide" style="vertical-align: top; display: inline-block;
              min-height: 99%; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">

             /*  A BUNCH OF TALL COLUMNS CONTAINING STACKED DIVS IS THE PAGE */

    </div> <!-- leftSide div -->
  </div> <!-- outerDiv -->
</div> <!-- wholePageDiv -->
```

I'm stumped.  On the one hand, the browser's vertical scroll bar works fine if I start with the browser window tall enough to show the whole page's height, and then collapse the browser to show only the top 1/2 of the page -- the vertical scrollbar appears correctly and I can scroll down to see the bottom 1/2 of the page.

But if I *start* by loading the page when the browser window is only tall enough to show the top 1/2 of the page -- the vertical scollbar needs to be there to allow scrolling down to see the bottom 1/2 of the page, but while it appears, it has no 'range,' no way to scroll the page down.

Do I have a conflict in my styles here?

Comment: Is this an accurate fiddle?: http://fiddle.jshell.net/DuLQE/1/show/

Comment: @JackPattishallJr.  Yes and no -- in your .tall, I'm not using floats and I do not have fixed height on the inner divs, the text content in the divs within the page can change.

Comment: This is a tough one to reproduce. Here's one more attempt: http://fiddle.jshell.net/DuLQE/6/show/ - Something like this? (the `white-space: nowrap` causes the lorem ipsum to not wrap, but hopefully the height of the DIVs are similar...)

Comment: @JackPattishallJr.  I removed the #leftSide div { line-height: 90px; }
from your example -- and the vertical scrollbar at the right edge of the browser window still doesn't reproduce what I'm seeing.  I must have something buried in the code somewhere that resets the height of one of these divs to match the height of the browser window **at load time only** and not at scroll time, but damned if I can find it.

Comment: I just now removed all the content, all the text divs, from the page and replaced it with all the text from your example and am able to still see my symptoms -- that helps significantly because it eliminates (as I expected) any code from the page consisting of divs and text.  I'm narrowing it down, your sample gave me a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Great! If your markup/css is on-line somewhere, I'd be happy to lend an extra pair of eyes. Otherwise, once you find the solution, I'd love to know what was causing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I backed out a lot of code changes by reverting to an older version of the source code and the problem was gone.  Sometimes it's important to keep an eye on the big picture and cut your losses, a lot of changes to the code caused this scrolling symptom and it saved time to just return to a version of the code before the problem existed.